# Does C reuse memory after reassignment?

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I'm writing a C program to calculate the path of a particle (similar to the three body problem). In my code I have typedef'ed structs to represent the particle, and a set of vectors to represent the particle's velocity, acceleration and position. As this is an iterative solution I have to recalculate all of these (and consequently malloc a new vector) thousands of times and reassign them to the parent struct in each iteration, like so:

```
while(collisionCheck(particle, mass0, mass1) == 0)
{
    particle-> velocity = recalculateVelocity(particle);
}
```

I'm concerned about how C will handle the orphaned struct, should I be freeing the old struct like this?

```
while(collisionCheck(particle, mass0, mass1) == 0)
{
    free(particle-> velocity);
    particle-> velocity = recalculateVelocity(particle);
}
```

Or will C garbage collect the orphans and reuse the memory space automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is not garbage collected, so it will *not* garbage collect anything. In order to free memory you *must* use the `free()` function after you've allocated with `malloc()`.

So the answer is, if `particle->velocity` is the only pointer to space you've previously allocated with `malloc()`, you must release the memory with `free()` before you assign to that pointer, as that will mean you no longer have *any* pointer to that space, and that is a [**memory leak**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).

Answer (score 4):

Well … C does *not* have *any* garbage collection.

For every memory region that you `malloc`, you're responsible for `free`:ing it, yourself.

However, once the memory has been `free`d, it will generally be re-used.

Answer (score 4):

Only free `particle->velocity` if it's a pointer and `recalculateVelocity()` actually creates a new struct (or whatever) and returns the pointer to it.

If you're not using `malloc()`, you must not use `free()`. If you've used `malloc()`, you have to use `free()`. Only exception here is `realloc()`.